# Converting UTC timestamp to ISO 8601 in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp

I have a timestamp that is in UTC

"2010-10-25 23:48:46 UTC"

I need to convert it into ISO 8601

"2010-10-29 06:09Z"

The documentation is confusing as hell - what is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I think you're trying to trick us.

The input date to your question is the *25th of October, 2010*, whilst the output is the ***29th** of October, 2010*. Well played!

Continuing on this nit-picking thread: your times are also completely different and you're missing the seconds from the output time.

Now for the true answer.

A little factoid first though: the ISO 8601 output in Ruby is similar to the "Combined date and time" output from [ISO 8601's Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

You've got a string and so you'll need to convert it into a `Time` object which you can do with `to_time`. Then it's simply a matter of calling `iso8601` on that object to get the ISO 8601 version:

```
"2010-10-25 23:48:46 UTC".to_time.iso8601
```

The `to_time` method is courtesy of Rails, whilst the `iso8601` is courtesy of Ruby's standard library.

Comment: Good answer, but I didn't get the first part (was that supposed to be humor?)

Comment: Damn! you saw through my plot to trick you folks. =P   Thanks for the great answer, i wonder why they do not just write that in the documentation!

Comment: @Mark Thomas: yes it was supposed to be humour. He gave an input and an output time that wouldn't match, ever. Tricksie little hobbit!

Comment: This works, but although his question asked how to do it in ruby, it didn't assume it was in the rails environment.

Comment: Related, thanks for pointing me at 'to_time' ~ Time.now.iso8601 formats like "2010-10-25T23:48:46Z", if you want to use '+00:00' instead of 'Z' (which I had to for a legacy system) Time.now.to_time.iso8601 appears to do this.

Answer (score 22):

After much experimenting, I find the Time library's parser to be better than DateTime, although the reasons escape me at the moment.  With that caveat, I always use Time rather than DateTime for this kind of stuff, and the ruby documentation is also difficult to grok as to why this is so,

```
require 'time'
puts Time.parse("2010-10-25 23:48:46 UTC").iso8601
"2010-10-25T23:48:46Z"
```

Comment: good pure ruby solution. Just want to add, if original time is not UTC, you may want this: `Time.parse("...").utc.iso8601`, otherwize you'll get the time suffixed with `+03:00` or some other value depending on the timezone original time string is given with. I mean instead of `Z`.

Answer (score 6):

Note: you have to convert (parse) a time string into a time object before you can apply the to_time method.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :016 > "2010-10-25 23:48:46 UTC".to_time.iso8601
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_time' for "2010-10-25 23:48:46 UTC":String
    from (irb):16
```

Correct procedure:

```
irb> ut = DateTime.parse("2010-10-25 23:48:46 UTC")

irb> ut.iso8601
 => "2010-10-25T23:48:46+00:00"
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding an answer to this super old question because if you're using Rails, there is no need to convert/parse it in the way the other answers here are telling you to do:

- If it's already a timestamp (e.g., a `created_at` or `updated_at` attribute), you can *directly* call the `iso8601` method on that timestamp (e.g., `object.created_at.iso8601`).
- The `iso8601` method also accepts a numeric argument to display fractional digits; you would use this if you want `2020-04-06T19:16:55.604Z` instead of `2020-04-06T19:16:55Z`.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-iso8601