# How to change default json time format of Active Support?

Tags: ruby, json, datetime, activesupport, iso8601

I don't want default json format of Active Support. So I put code in app.rb of my project.
`ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format = false`

it changed time format from `iso8601` to `strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %z')`. But i want to change time format `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')`.

```
Time.now.to_json => output "2016/06/20 10:57:43 +0300" but i want to format "2016-06-20 10:57:43 +0300"
```

My project is a Ruby on Sinatra.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put your code?

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format = false
```

Please try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18360367/2245697

Comment: I put it in app.rb file of my project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#as_json`. For example, using Rails instead of Sinatra:

```rb
# new file config/initializers/timestamp_serialization.rb

class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def as_json(options = nil)
    time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  end
end
```

The reason for this is that the [source `as_json` method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4.2/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-as_json) only accepts two possibilities: iso8601 enabled, in which case it uses `iso8601`, or iso8601 disabled, in which case it uses `"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`:

```rb
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb, line 176
def as_json(options = nil)
  if ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format
    xmlschema(ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.time_precision)
  else
    %(#{time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")} #{formatted_offset(false)})
  end
end
```

(note: `xmlschema` is an alias for `iso8601`)

I ran into this while running an upgrade from Rails 3.2 to 4.0, which had the side effect of changing all the serialized timestamps from 0-digit precision ISO 8601 format to 3-digit precision. Unfortunately, Rails only lets you configure the precision by itself [starting at 4.1](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-as_json), so I had to override the method entirely.